# JavaScript - Capture repeated group

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript (or VBScript) Is it possible to separately capture from *%n:32+5000* the following groups?:

- Capture group 1: %n
- Capture group 2: :32
- Capture group 3: +5000

I tried a search through this forum about capturing repeated groups, but the examples given were either in a different language like .NET or the asker wasn't asking specifically how to do what I need.

The best attempt I've made thus far is `(%n)(([:\+]\d+){0,2})` with global turned on. Also, I am using https://regex101.com/r/qBylQX/1 to help me visualize what's happening; but, so far I haven't cracked it.

Notes:

- only one instance of %n is allowed per
- only one appearance of :\d+ is allowed per match
- only one appearance of +\d+ is allowed per match.
- the pattern can appear anywhere in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
(%n)(?:(:\d+)(\+\d+)?)?
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/4umhXM/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %n                       '%n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of \3 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this pattern `(%n)(([:\+]\d+){0,2})` can also match 2 times `:\d+` or 2 times `+\d+` as both the `:` and `+` are in the character class.

Repeating a capture group like `([:\+]\d+){0,2}` will only capture the value of the last iteration in the group.

As this repetition is inside the outer capture group 2, the group 2 value will contain the whole match and you don't have a nice separation of values in groups that you are after.

---

According to the notes only one occurrence can of either one of them can be in the match.

If you want to match both combinations of `:` and `+` but if they can not be the same, you can use a capture group with a backreference.

The values are in group 1, 3 and 4.

```
(%n)(?:([:+])(\d+)(?:(?!\2)([:+]\d+))?)?(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(%n)` Capture **group 1**, match `%n`
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `([:+])` Capture **group 2**, match either `:` or `+`
  - `(\d+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ digits
  - `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

    - `(?!\2)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not the same value as captured in group 2
    - `([:+]\d+)` Capture **group 4**, match `:` or `+`
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AcxOx/1)

```js
const regex = /(%n)(?:([:+])(\d+)(?:(?!\2)([:+]\d+))?)?(?!\S)/;
[
  "%n:32+5000",
  "%n:32",
  "%n+5000",
  "%n",
  "%n+32:5000",
  "%n+32",
  "%n:5000",
  "%n:32:5000",
  "%n+32+5000"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${regex.test(s)} ==> ${s}`));
```